# Trying to display limited number of images in teasers

Tags: css, css-selectors

I try to style my website using pseudo-selectors to display limited number of elements (images) in my teasers. I have been doing some research through Google, found the most proper way using nth-child(n). I could not find however why it does not work for me. If I use nth-child(n+5), it should be displaying first four images, all the others should not be displayd. It does not work at all. Am I thinking it good way or the problem is more complicated?

The code is like this:

```
.node-teaser .field-type-image  img {
    float: left;
    width: 24.6%;
    padding:0.2%;
}

.node-teaser .field-type-image img:nth-child(n+5){
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `-` (negative sign) in front of the `n` notation to specify only a number of elements.

In your case, if you want only 4 elements to be displayed:

```
.node-teaser .field-type-image img{
    display: none;
}

.node-teaser .field-type-image img:nth-child(-n+4){
    display: block;
}
```

Why?

> Using "-n" values seems a little weird, because if the end result is
>   negative there is no match, so you'll need to add to the equation to
>   get it back positive again. As it turns out, this is a rather clever
>   technique. You can use it to select the "first n elements" with
>   "-n+3":
>
> -0 + 3 = 3 = 3rd Element
>
> -1 + 3 = 2 = 2nd Element
>
> -2 + 3 = 1 = 1st Element
>
> -3 + 3 = 0 = no match

Read the full, very good article here: http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/